# Indefinite integral of $\int \frac 1 x \operatorname{arsech} \frac x a \, \mathrm d x$

Tags: indefinite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

Spiegel's "Mathematical Handbook of Formulas and Tables" (Schaum, 1968), item $14.668$ gives the indefinite integral of the area hyperbolic secant (that is, the "inverse" hyperbolic secant) as:

$$\int \frac 1 x \operatorname{arsech} \frac x a \, \mathrm d x = -\frac 1 2 \ln (a/x) \ln (4 a/x) - \frac {(x/a)^2} {2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2} - \frac {1 \cdot 3 (x/a)^4} {2 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 \cdot 4} - \cdots$$

This can be expressed as:

$$\int \frac 1 x \operatorname{arsech}  \frac x a \, \mathrm d x = -\frac 1 2 \ln \left({\frac a x}\right) \ln \left({\frac {4 a} x}\right) - \sum_{n \mathop \ge 0} \frac {(2 n)!} {2^{2 n} (n!)^2 (2 n)^2} \left({\frac x a}\right)^{2 n} + C$$

Getting *nearly* there is easy enough.

I take as my starting point the power series expansion of the area hyperbolic cosine of $\dfrac x a$:

$$\operatorname{arcosh} x = \ln \frac {2 x} a - \left({\sum_{n \mathop = 1}^\infty \frac {(2 n)!} {2^{2 n} (n!)^2 (2 n)} \left({\frac a x}\right)^{2 n} }\right)$$

(This is derived from the result in Spiegel, item $20.40$.)

From it I get the same for the area hyperbolic secant $\operatorname{arsech}$ of $\dfrac x a$, as it's just the $\operatorname{arcosh}$ of $\dfrac a x$:

$$\operatorname{arsech} x = \ln \frac {2 a} x - \left({\sum_{n \mathop = 1}^\infty \frac {(2 n)!} {2^{2 n} (n!)^2 (2 n)} \left({\frac x a}\right)^{2 n} }\right)$$

and integrate term by term (justified by Fubini's theorem, I believe) to get me eventually to:

$$\int \frac 1 x \operatorname{arsech} \frac x a \, \mathrm d x = -\frac 1 2 \ln^2 \left({\dfrac x {2 a} }\right) + \sum_{n \mathop = 0}^\infty \frac {(2 n)!} {2^{2 n} (n!)^2 (2 n)^2} \left({\frac x a}\right)^{2 n} + C$$

During the course of the above I inverted the reciprocal in the logarithm of the integrand to get it into a standard form for integration $\displaystyle \int \dfrac {\ln (c x)} x \mathrm d x = \dfrac {\ln^2 {c x} } 2$ which I think I got right.

The above is consistent with the result quoted in Schaum for the indefinite integral for the area hyperbolic cosine, where the logarithm term was left as a square.

So there are $2$ questions outstanding:

1. How do you actually get from $\ln^2 \left({\dfrac x {2 a} }\right)$ to $\ln \left({\dfrac a x}\right) \ln \left({\dfrac {4 a} x}\right)$? I get that they will differ by a constant which can be subsumed into a constant of integration, but manipulation of $\ln^2 \left({\dfrac x {2 a} }\right)$ gets me only as far as $\left({\ln \left({\dfrac a x}\right)}\right)^2 + 2 \ln 2 \ln \dfrac a x + \left({\ln 2}\right)^2$ and at this point I can't see how to proceed. I can't reduce the $2 \ln 2 \ln \dfrac a x$ and get it to go the way I want it to.
2. How did Spiegel ever get to that $\ln \left({\dfrac a x}\right) \ln \left({\dfrac {4 a} x}\right)$ term in the first place? His quoted result for the indefinite integral for the area hyperbolic cosine has that term in the $\ln^2$ form, the same as what I got for the area hyperbolic secant. That is, what direction could he have taken with his integration so as to land upon a result in that form? I can't see why he would deliberately manipulate it into that form, as he is happy enough to leave the indefinite integral for the area hyperbolic cosine in the $\ln^2$ form.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calculating indefinite integral, the inconsistency is obvious, the difference between two results must be a ***constant***!

1. The difference:

$$\ln \left(\frac{a}{x}\right) \ln \left(\frac{4 a}{x}\right)-\ln ^2\left(\frac{x}{2 a}\right)=
\ln \left(\frac{a}{x}\right) \left[\ln \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)+2 \log (2)\right]-\left[\ln \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)+\ln (2)\right]^2
=-\ln ^2(2)$$

2. The reason: the real domain of ${\rm arcsech(x)}$ is $[0,1]$, thus when you change the operations of expansion and integral, you must be careful, i.e.
   $$
   \int\to\int_a^x
   $$
   In other words, you should have
   $$
   \int_a^x \frac{\ln (2 a)-\ln (z)}{z} \, dz=-\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(\frac{a}{x}\right) \ln \left(\frac{4 a}{x}\right)
   $$

Comment: Please, there is no need to shout at me. I appreciate that they are allowed to differ by a constant, I said that in the question: "I get that they will differ by a constant which can be subsumed into a constant of integration ...". Thank you for your help in achieving that final step, it escaped me how it could be done. Now, what's your take on the initial approach that may be taken to arrive at the $\ln(a/x) \ln (4a/x)$ result in the first place?

Comment: @PrimeMover I am sorry for those unnecessary words, please just ignore them.